# Why didn't Bellatrix volunteer to lend her wand to Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter

In the first chapter of *Deathly Hallows*, Voldemort states that he needs a new wand, and will therefore borrow one from a Death Eater. Unfortunately, nobody seems really thrilled by the idea, and he ends up taking Lucius' wand.

> “As I was saying,” continued Voldemort, looking again at the tense faces of his followers, “I understand better now. I shall need, for instance, to borrow a wand from one of you before I go to kill Potter.”
>
> The faces around his displayed nothing but shock; he might have announced that he wanted to borrow one of their arms.
>
> “No volunteers?” said Voldemort. “Let’s see... Lucius, I see no reason for you to have a wand anymore.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 1, "The Dark Lord Ascending"</sub>

You could argue that it had always been Voldemort's intention to take Lucius' wand, since he resents Lucius for his failure at bringing him the prophecy at the end of *Order of the Phoenix*, and that nothing would have changed his mind.

I can even understand that he would not want to borrow Bellatrix's, since she is a skilled fighter and duellists (presumably) fight better with their own wand; it would make sense to keep her at full potential.

My problem is, it happens that Bellatrix Lestrange is in the exact same room, and Bellatrix is pretty much the most obsessed extremist example you can get. Let's not expand on the multiple times that obsession was pictured, but here are at least *four* instances in a dozen lines from *this very chapter*:

> “My Lord,” said a dark woman halfway down the table, **her voice constricted with emotion**, “it is an honor to have you here, in our family’s house. **There can be no higher pleasure**.”
>
> She sat beside her sister, as unlike her in looks, with her dark hair and heavily lidded eyes, as she was in bearing and demeanor; where Narcissa sat rigid and impassive, **Bellatrix leaned toward Voldemort, for mere words could not demonstrate her longing for closeness**.
>
> “No higher pleasure,” repeated Voldemort, his head tilted a little to one side as he considered Bellatrix. “That means a great deal, Bellatrix, from you.”
>
> **Her face flooded with color; her eyes welled with tears of delight.**
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 1, "The Dark Lord Ascending"</sub>

Bellatrix has shown time and time again that she will do *anything* for her master, and would even be prepared to let her children go on a deadly mission for him. My, she even uses the words *give them up*!

> She *[Narcissa]* crumpled, falling at his feet, sobbing and moaning on the floor.
>
> "My only son... my only son..."
>
> "You should be proud!" said Bellatrix ruthlessly. "If I had sons, I would be glad to give them up to the service of the Dark Lord!"
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 2, "Spinner's end"</sub>

**So, why would she not jump at the occasion to prove her devotion by giving the Dark Lord her wand?**

- I initially thought she had no time to do so, but the first quote suggests that there was a bit of time when the statement was made (*"Let's see..."*);
- Various quotes from the second chapter of *Half-Blood Prince* seem to indicate Voldemort is a bit colder to Bellatrix, in the wake of the blunder at the Ministry, but that was roughly a year before the scene I'm talking about, and even if the situation had not improved, I reckon that would have made Bellatrix even more lenient to give him her wand;
- Voldemort does discredit her by mentioning how her niece (Tonks) recently married a "beast", but that is later in the scene;
- Depending on how much credit you give to *Cursed Child*, Bellatrix even went as far as

  > giving him a child. I'm not a parent, but based on what I've heard of pregnancy and delivery, you might as well lend the partner an arm. (*"he might have announced that he wanted to borrow one of their arms"*)

Comment: i think you have the answer in your first quote. "The faces around his displayed nothing but shock; he might have announced that he wanted to borrow one of their arms." the shock of the question gives them all a moment of hesitation, as voldemort would have known it would, and he talks right through there shock, to take the wand he intended to from the start. after he has already decided on luciases she can breathe a breath of relief at not needing to volunteer

Comment: also , https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60277/why-does-nobody-want-to-give-voldemort-their-wand

Comment: @Himarm ah, had not thought to check Movies.SE. I still kind of think she'd be screaming "ME!!" whenever Voldemort starts a question with "Who could", but if you excuse me, I shall now go and see what the primarily concerned has to say :)

Comment: i like bella's answer and it kind of re-enforces the idea of the shock even bellatrix would have about giving up her wand. And something that may have been an internal crisis for her, love of voldemort = love of wand, was taken out of her hands by voldemorts fast choice of lucias. nice question +1, and @bella nice answer +1

Comment: Note that Bellatrix did not have children when she said that, so couldn't really know how she would feel if she did.  But she is a total psycho, so even if she had been a mother at the time she might very well *still* be far more attached to her wand than to her children.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't think it's necessarily about being a *psycho*, throughout most of human history mothers have raised children to go to war and hunt bears and be valiant and brave and noble. Think the Spartan appeal "With your shield, or on it."

Comment: @Au101, I'm fairly sure either or both of the Malfoys (as just one example) would have sacrificed their wands far more readily than their son.  Basically, I just don't think the Spartan thing is part of ordinary British wizarding culture.  But "psycho" was mainly just an observation. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sure but I mean, my point is that it's not about Bellatrix valuing her wand more than her son, it's about raising an adult who can stand on their own two feet and fight the good fight and win glory and bring about the new wizarding order and serve the Dark Lord (versus raising a wimp and a failure), rather than neutering herself and giving up all her status and her role in the revolution and her place at Voldemort's side and the symbol of her magic and power and, indeed, the outlet of her power

Comment: @HarryJohnston Or she's just a fanatic...Yes that fits better although certainly you could argue that she's close to a psychopath if not (doesn't change the fact she's absolutely a fanatic though).

Comment: **You could argue that it had always been Voldemort's intention to take Lucius' wand, since he resents Lucius for his failure at bringing him the prophecy at the end of Order of the Phoenix, and that nothing would have changed his mind.** Absolutely that was the case. He mocked the Malfoy family throughout that meeting didn't he? And yes your own wand is best - and in the case of Bella's wand it's Unyielding so even more a reason for Voldemort to not have it. And I cringe at the word 'fangirl' ... that's so not Bellatrix.

Comment: @Au101, in this context, it doesn't seem to me that she was talking about allowing her hypothetical sons to stand on their own two feet and so on, she was talking about deliberately sending them to be slaughtered.

Comment: @Pryftan well, just because he wouldn't have taken her wand, doesn't mean she couldn't have tried. Think of Hermione still trying to participate and get Gryffindor House Points in Snape's classes ;) as for "fangirl", alright, alright, I'm expeditive with that one. If you've got a better suggestion (or several), feel free to add them here, I'd be glad to pick a better-suited one.

Comment: `Depending on how much credit you give to Cursed Child` none at all because it’s a bunch of non-sense, might be an appealing stage production but that’s where it’s positives end...

Comment: Well... let's see. Loyal fanatic. Extremist. Or if you want to look at her desire - obsessed. Those all fit her. And yes he could have tried if he even knew about that - but it certainly would have been something of an issue. Even so though he simply wanted to further humiliate Lucious and his family. He resented it and this all contributed to Narcissa lying to Voldemort in the end about whether Harry was alive or not.

Comment: @Pryftan alright, let's go with obsessed extremist ;D

Comment: Much better! I'm glad you edited it in too (for I wouldn't have). And I completely agree with @Edlothiad - CC is absolute rubbish to say the least (and I am appreciative of the comment because it's a thought I had I just already had included other things and cba adding anything else).

Comment: @Pryftan I always knew I liked you, but now I like you even more! ;)

Comment: @Bellatrix Ha! Same goes :) I have a lot of fun with you! :) And you really do remind me of her which as I'm sure you know does not mean I think of you as a raving psychopath who's hell bent on torturing and murdering people (but which I suspect many people would think I am suggesting); it's your passion for this, your dedication and the fun you have with it! I am very curious what comment you were replying to though; or was it meant to be in your answer? Anyway I appreciate the comment a lot and it's more than mutual! :))

Comment: @Bellatrix Ah. I might know now :) I forgot about the other comment (with a bloody spelling error too - it's Lucius not Lucious but I have this recollection that I accidentally added that to my system dictionary...). Maybe you mean that you're a loyal fanatic even to the extreme and obsessional? Is that the comment? Well you know it's completely true and you should be proud of it! :)

Comment: @Pryftan Wow, thanks! :) I’m glad you do, I do too! :) Thank you, I’m honored to be compared to her!! :) Whatever others think I’m not doubtful in the slightest, after all I chose to take her name as my own! You’re absolutely welcome, and thanks a lot to you too! :)

Comment: As far as the comment I was replying to, I meant to say I liked several of yours! :) First, I appreciate your objection to the word ‘fangirl’ on the behalf of Bellatrix, and of course I’m glad for that, I don’t think of her as one either! :) I also love how you appreciate her loyalty as many people don’t. Your comments on her wand being unyielding are also good, I’m still trying to figure out how to logically add it in! In addition, I love how you call CC absolute rubbish, I share your opinion very much on that! Mainly, my reply was about your objection to ‘fangirl’ and calling CC rubbish! :)

Comment: @Bellatrix You know what? I also understand very well the value of Pity. Miss Bella was indoctrinated and that itself is a very significant thing to consider. Yes some people ignore such indoctrination but it doesn't mean they're necessarily nice; look at your dear cousin Sirius who was a really callous bully and nearly got Severus killed by a werewolf (or turned into a werewolf). Even Dumbledore says that one who lived without love should be pitied and that includes the Dark Lord.

Comment: @Bellatrix ...and I can't stand the term fangirl/fanboy and far too many people don't appreciate loyalty: and they're disloyal even. Nobody is 'just something' and whether she tortured or murdered anyone doesn't change the fact she was loyal, dedicated, passionate and she wasn't a witch to be underestimated - as Sirius found out, of course; on the other hand Molly shouldn't be underestimated either. I'm unsure how to best put the Unyielding part into your answer but if I think of anything I'll mention it; it's still a good answer though!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bellatrix wants to fight. She wants to be the most honoured death eater.

> [T]he woman with the heavy-lidded eyes looked up at Crouch and called, 'The Dark Lord will rise again, Crouch! Throw us into Azkaban, we will wait! He will rise again and will come for us, he will reward us beyond any of his other supporters! We alone were faithful! We alone tried to find him!'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - p.517 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 30, *The Pensieve*

That's who she is. That's what she wants. That's want she went to Azkaban for. She doesn't really want to go into this battle with some second-hand wand and she certainly does not want to sit this one out on the touchline with the half-time oranges and the fat wheezy boys with a note from matron.

You're also right to bring up her failure at the Ministry and Tonks. Although Voldemort doesn't taunt her about Tonks until later we can gather that things haven't been going well for Bella really. She wants to prove herself. She wants to regain favour.

> 'Many of our oldest family trees become a little diseased over time,' he said, as Bellatrix gazed at him, breathless and imploring. 'You must prune yours, must you not, to keep it healthy? Cut away those parts that threaten the health of the rest.'
>
> 'Yes, my Lord,' whispered Bellatrix, and her eyes swam with tears of gratitude again. 'At the first chance!'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - pp.16-7 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 1, *The Dark Lord Ascending*

Again she doesn't wanna miss out on her chance to fight and succeed.

But most of all, to deprive a witch of her wand is to virtually deprive her of her magic. But to deprive a Death Eater of her wand is even worse, surely? These are people who base their self-worth and their identity on their magic. Carrying a wand is a symbol, it's one of the rights that wizards denied Goblins and that's one of the things that Goblins resented about wizards. To remove a wand from a Death Eater is to utterly humiliate them. In Bellatrix's own words:

> 'Your authority!' she sneered, attempting to wrench her hand from his grasp. 'You lost your authority when you lost your wand, Lucius!'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.373 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 23, *Malfoy Manor*

I mean, you have it there in your own quote:

> 'No volunteers?' said Voldemort. 'Let's see ... Lucius, **I see no reason for you to have a wand any more.**'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.14 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 1, *The Dark Lord Ascending*

That's what taking the wand means, isn't it? Your services are no longer required.

There is no way that volunteering to give up your wand would impress Voldemort  or demonstrate that you are a worthy servant. On the contrary, it would be being willing to live like a Muggle. A true wizard, with true wizarding sense, uses their wand all the time in their daily lives.

> There was a deafening *clang*. Merope had dropped one of the pots.
>
> *'Pick it up!'* Gaunt bellowed at her. 'That's it, grub on the floor like some filthy Muggle, what's your wand for, you useless sack of muck?'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.194 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 10, *The House of Gaunt*

Having a wand and using a wand is integral to the kind of ideology a Death Eater would have. It would be a contemptible thing to hand over your wand willingly. It would be being prepared to stoop and pick things up off the floor like some Muggle. It would not be a good way to demonstrate her love or get back on side.

Comment: I presume by Wheezy you mean Ron et al? If so remember only Severus knew that there would be seven Potters.

Comment: @Pryftan Hehe no it was a reference to the extremely popular British sitcom Blackadder, starring Rowan Atkinson, there wasn't anything to read into it Harry Potter  wise :)

Comment: Ah. I don't watch TV though I can't say I don't enjoy Fawlty Towers and also The IT Crowd, for example. But I'm disappointed in you! You could have made it a pun! Ah well... thanks for clarifying - and I was going to suggest you clarify in the answer but it seems you removed it which is probably for the best (that or I'm extremely blind right now and I totally missed it...).

Comment: 'K, I'll be honest, I tergiversated a bit, but I accepted this answer because IMO, it gives more insight about Bellatrix's view on the matter (see the quote on authority), and more generally speaking about Death Eaters (Gaunt wasn't one, but would totally have been, given the chance). The other answer is a tiny bit more generalist, but still very good too!

Comment: @Jenayah Would you mind me pleading my answer’s case? (Usually I wouldn’t bother, but I'm particularly invested here.) I don’t think this is quite right, because there’s nothing really implying (until the Dark Lord actually takes Lucius’s wand) that whoever volunteered their wand would be somehow ‘stripped’ of their right to carry a wand. I agree that Death Eaters would disdain the idea of not having any wand more than most, but I don’t think that comes into play in this specific situation. That’s why I’ve based mine around her wanting to keep her own wand. I’ve also updated to address this.

Comment: @Bellatrix, sure all constructive debates are always welcome :) the way I see it, the above show that this was the reason they were astonished - not mostly because they indeed value their wand (albeit the "borrow an arm"), but because while he could very well go fetch one somewhere else, he seems to snarkily reduce them to Muggles, Squibs, etc, everything these guys hate. As for your edit, I accepted the answer before it; but sure, as said in the question Bellatrix is too good of a duellist to be left completely without a wand.

Comment: @Jenayah Thanks! :) I’m convinced now - this answer gets right to the heart of why Bellatrix would be insulted at the suggestion that she’d want to give up her wand. :)

Comment: @Au101 Here’s an upvote, great answer! ;) Bellatrix herself approves! ;)

Answer (score 34):

## Bellatrix‘s wand, like most wizards’, would be like a part of her.

Wizards’ wands are very important to them. The relationship between a wizard and their wand grows stronger as they continue using it over the years. The more they use it, the better it works for them, and the connection between the wizard and their wand increases as they use it and grows stronger over time. Asking them to give up their wand would be like asking them to cut off their arm.

> “The best results, however, must always come where there is the strongest affinity between wizard and wand. These connections are complex. An initial attraction, and then a mutual quest for experience, the wand learning from the wizard, the wizard from the wand.” <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24 (The Wandmaker)</sup></sub>

Bellatrix had (probably) been using the same wand for her entire life, and it had learned from her enough that when Hermione had it, she said it ‘felt like a bit of her’. Bellatrix probably felt the same way about it, and was unwilling to simply give it up, even for the Dark Lord.

> “Hermione looked frightened that the wand might sting or bite her as she picked it up.
>
> ‘I hate this thing,’ she said in a low voice. ‘I really hate it. It feels all wrong, it doesn’t work properly for me … it’s like a bit of *her*.” <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26 (Gringotts)</sup></sub>

Hermione suspected that the wand was Bellatrix’s original wand, and therefore it’d be fairly connected to her and adapted to her style of magic by her having used it exclusively for years.

> “But that’s my point!’ said Hermione. ‘This is the wand that tortured Neville’s mum and dad, and who knows how many other people? This is the wand that killed Sirius!” <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26 (Gringotts)</sup></sub>

She likely was attached to her wand, and didn’t want to give it up. The Dark Lord could relatively easily get a wand, and she probably didn’t want to part with hers. In addition, if she did give it up, it’d mean she would be in the midst of a wizarding war with a less-than-optimal wand. Actually taking part in the war to the best of her ability would be very important to her. She’d want to be front and center in the battles, so she wouldn’t want to handicap herself by having to change wands to one that won’t work as well. She’d know it’d decrease her ability to duel if she could no longer use her own wand, and she definitely wouldn’t want that to happen. She thrived on battle.

> “Potter, you cannot win against me!’ she cried.
>
> He could hear her moving to the right, trying to get a clear shot of him. He backed around the statue away from her, crouching behind the centaur’s legs, his head level with the house-elf’s.
>
> ‘I was and am the Dark Lord’s most loyal servant. I learned the Dark Arts from him, and I know spells of such power that you, pathetic little boy, can never hope to compete –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 36 (The Only One He Ever Feared)*</sup></sub>

Since like most wizards she’d likely be attached to her wand, and in her specific case she’d need a reliable one for duels, she’d probably not want to willingly volunteer to give it up when she doesn’t have to. We do see an example of how a wizard feels when forced to part with his wand. When Harry’s wand is broken, he’s extremely upset, and he feels like he lost a part of his magical power.

> “The holly and phoenix wand was nearly severed in two. One fragile strand of phoenix feather kept both pieces hanging together. The wood had splintered apart completely. Harry took it into his hands as though it was a living thing that had suffered a terrible injury. He could not think properly: everything was a blur of panic and fear.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 17 (Bathilda’s Secret)*</sup></sub>

He considered losing it worse than many of the other horrible things he’d experienced, including physical injuries, and felt vulnerable without it. Though this was partially because his wand defended him from the Dark Lord of its own accord, from what we see of the relationship between wizards and their wands, most wizards probably feel somewhat the same about their wands.

> “Without realising it, he was digging his fingers into his arms as if he were trying to resist physical pain. He had spilled his own blood more times than he could count; he had lost all the bones in his right arm once; this journey had already given him scars to his chest and forearm to join those on his hand and forehead, but never, until this moment, had he felt himself to be fatally weakened, vulnerable and naked, as though the best part of his magical power had been torn from him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 18 (The Life and Lies of Albus Dumbledore)*</sup></sub>

Bellatrix would know there would be other ways for the Dark Lord to get a wand, so there was no real need for her to volunteer hers but for the possible chance of impressing the Dark Lord (who seemed more to be taunting them all than expecting someone to actually do it), it was unlikely he’d go without a wand. Though she valued the Dark Lord, she still wouldn’t want to just give her wand up, especially since it’d hamper her ability to fight for the Dark Lord and Death Eaters if he took it.

## It probably *wasn’t* that she was afraid she’d remain wandless.

The reason she didn’t want to volunteer her wand probably isn’t because  she was afraid that she wouldn’t have *any wand at all* after giving hers up. The Dark Lord hadn’t said that whoever gave him their wand wouldn’t be allowed to get a replacement, and wizards do sometimes have to get replacement wands. From what the Dark Lord says, it doesn’t seem like she’d be concerned she’d have *no* wand, and be no better than a Muggle. The only time he implied someone was ‘unworthy’ to have *any* wand was when he said he would take Lucius’s instead. The only reason why Lucius ‘lost his authority when he lost his wand’ is because of *how* he lost it - after not getting any offers, the Dark Lord told Lucius it wasn’t necessary for him to have a wand, implying he’s useless.

> “No volunteers?’ said Voldemort. ‘Let’s see … Lucius, I see no reason for you to have a wand any more.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

However, the way he asked for volunteers to give him a wand, he didn’t imply they were giving away their right to a wand if they did, just that they were giving him their specific wand. Bellatrix herself eventually has to get another wand because Harry and co. took hers, so her wand was forcibly taken away from her by them, and this doesn’t get in the way of her getting a new wand since she has one at the battle. Even if the Dark Lord was upset at her ‘allowing’ her wand to be taken away, he still (presumably) allowed her to get another one.

> “Bellatrix was still fighting too, fifty yards away from Voldemort, and like her master she duelled three at once: Hermione, Ginny and Luna, all battling their hardest, but Bellatrix was equal to them, and Harry’s attention was diverted as a Killing Curse shot so close to Ginny that she missed death by an inch –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

Bellatrix, specifically, didn’t have much reason to think the Dark Lord would leave her without a wand at that time. He hadn’t yet mentioned her niece reproducing with a werewolf, and while she fell out of favor a bit after the failure to get the prophecy, she didn’t seem to be being punished in the same way the Malfoy family was. Therefore, her reasoning was probably based on a desire to keep *her own* wand instead of getting a new one that wouldn’t work as well for her.

Comment: Well blimey that was fast. You really thought that through did you? Ever felt like you might have to explain yourself to someone at some point? :)

Comment: @Jenayah Thanks! :) Yes, I did think this through, quite a lot actually and for a while before. Now I get the chance to explain myself! :)

Comment: Oh, so that _definitely_ reinforces my theory that you have a notebook/Word file somewhere with a bunch of answers to Harry Potter questions which haven't been asked yet, ready to be posted as soon as they appear on the frontpage.

Comment: Nevertheless, as usual, great answer, and as @Himarm points out above I like the suggestion of an internal crisis for such a wicked character. +1, soon to be accepted if no better answer is posted, blahblahblah, same old song. :p

Comment: Another thing to consider about your (well okay - for those who don't understand it or miss it at a quick glance - Bellatrix's) wand is it is Unyielding. That makes it harder to win over and even when you do 'win' it it is very resistant to working right for the new owner.

Comment: @Pryftan Do you have that from somewhere in particular? There are several wands described by Ollivander as unyielding—I always took that to refer simply to the hardness of the wood. There are Wanda described as pliant or flexible as well, which would then be easier to bend in your hand (but harder to snap). Do you have any sources that state that these properties have to do with how easily mastered the sands are?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Pottermore. On my profile (and I have Unyielding) it says this: **Wand flexibility or rigidity denotes the degree of adaptability and willingness to change possessed by the wand-and-owner pair - although, again, this factor ought not to be considered separately from the wand wood, core and length, nor of the owner’s life experience and style of magic, all of which will combine to make the wand in question unique.** It's not the only thing though - core is another issue (mine is also Phoenix core something both of these I expected somehow... but Unyielding is relevant).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet See also: https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-lengths-and-flexibilit

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh and perhaps you also meant (I was dead tired - in fact I am almost always knackered...) about Bella's wand being Unyielding? Ollivander says it: **'Walnut and dragon heartstring,' he said. 'Twelve-and-three-quarter inches. Unyielding. This wand belonged to Bellatrix Lestrange.'** Hopefully that suffices :)

Comment: @Miss Bella The link I gave to Janus might also be of use to add from? The writing is by Rowling herself and she gives a number of factors that play into the willingness of a wand to be won and used. And since you (that is Bella) is a formidable warrior with a lot of experience and the fact Unyielding wand is a good reason for your Lord to not use it - not that I believe he actually knew this (but still something that maybe can be integrated? I haven't any ideas atm though).

Comment: @Pryftan The Pottermore quote is very interesting. I never connected those two things at all. (I must have been either knackered or just off my rocker, too, to miss that autocorrect had turned ‘wands’ into both ‘Wanda’ and ‘sands’ in my last comment…)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet :)) Yes well it happens. I did see it and wondered what you were on about but context is a beautiful thing that people tend to overlook... Maybe Miss Bella can integrate this into her answer but right now I'm unsure how - and I'm off for many hours now - and I should probably drop out of this part anyway as I can only imagine the website is about to whine about 'chatting' and other nonsense.

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks a lot!! :) I definitely think that an unyielding wand would be difficult for the Dark Lord to use properly, since it wouldn’t want to give its loyalty.

Comment: @Miss Bella - 'Always,' said Pryftan. But yes you're quite right; as it is he was afraid to use the Elder Wand against poor Severus (though he got a little rash after that but let's be honest; that **obnoxious little bitty baby Harry** had irked him far too often so we can excuse his excitement!). The question though is whether the Dark Lord knew that about your wand; I suspect he didn't and he certainly didn't understand wandlore even to his undoing but the fact of the matter is he respected you and knew you were a formidable opponent: he was furious when Molly killed you, for example...

Comment: Perhaps when you're discussing how Bella likely used the wand for her entire life and how it learnt from her and there was a bond between the two - could that be where you bring up Unyielding? You might point out that it's unlikely she understood the meaning of it but she might somehow sense the strong bond. And certainly Voldemort would never ask Bella to give up her wand because he knew how good of a dueller and how dedicated she is but that's not really relevant to Unyielding so much as why neither Voldemort nor Bella would want her to give up her wand.